# How to post data to mongo collection using Mean stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I have a object that contains firstname and lastname from client it is printing in client factory so i am new to backend development so i created user schema and api to post the data but it is throwing 404 error . Error mentioned below in question. Any idea what is implemented wrong ?

clientFactory.js

```
 create : function(userData) {
            console.log('factory',userData);
            return $http.post('/api/users', userData);

        }
```

Server code

app > routes.js

```
  module.exports = function(app) {

      app.use('api/users', require('./api/user'));
      app.get('*', function(req, res) {
          res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
          // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, ''../public/views/index.html'')); 
      });

  };
```

Folders under app > api > user

user.index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./user.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.post('/',controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

user.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

user.controller.js

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  User.createAsync(req.body)
    .then(responseWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Error

```
angular.js:12410 POST http://localhost:8080/api/users 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12410
p @ angular.js:12155
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11908
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16648
$eval @ angular.js:17972
$digest @ angular.js:17786
$apply @ angular.js:18080
(anonymous) @ angular.js:26749
cg @ angular.js:3613
d @ angular.js:3601
angular.js:14328 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"Cannot POST /api/users\n","status":404,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/users","data":{"firstName":"Kun","lastName":"Zhang"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular error stack trace is very clear.
You do not handle this specific endpoint for your POST query in your express router.

So the server throw a *404 error*, as it should.

Try something like this:

```
router
    .post('/api/users', function (req, res) {
       // do what you want with your user here
    })
```

With express (and NodeJS) you must explicitly specify each access to server resources.

As side note, you are pretty close to this but try to keep your application logic simple for maintenability.

Comment: I am using `app.use` in routes and have router.post already in index.js , why we need url again ?

Comment: Because this doesn't work... Have you tried what I suggest ? You will be able to modularize your code when the router will be functional anyway.