# How to check mongo database is connected?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have mongodb up and running for the application how can i make sure when application start it is connected with db ?

app.js

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
var db = require('./config/db');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
mongoose.connect(db.url); 
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes
app.listen(port);                                  
console.log('listening on port ' + port);          
exports = module.exports = app;
```

config > db.js

```
module.exports = {
        url : 'mongodb://localhost/test-dev'
    }
```

Comment: Well... have you tried writing and reading a document from a collection?

Comment: yes i did and here i asked question but answer confuses me , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644624/how-to-post-data-to-mongo-collection-using-mean-stack/41645754#41645754 i tried provided answer but it did not work so i am trying to make sure if database is connected first

Comment: Please check the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) first. The third code snippet is an exact answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks its printing connected.