# How to use express middleware to handle all routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have issue setting up routes for user in below code, I want to use express middleware and trying routes using `app.use`.

`index.js` is invoking user controller method once api's is being called So in below code i am trying to post data `api/users` from client but it returns 404.

How can i fix this issue using below routes setup ?

server.js

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
var db = require('./config/db');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
mongoose.connect(db.url); 
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes
require('./config/express')(app); 
app.listen(port);                                  
console.log('listening on port ' + port);          
exports = module.exports = app;
```

app > routes.js

```
 module.exports = function(app) {


        app.use('api/users', require('./api/user'));
        app.get('*', function(req, res) {
            res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
           // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, ''../public/views/index.html'')); 
        });

    };
```

config > express.js

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
// import errorHandler from 'errorhandler';
var path = require('path');
// import lusca from 'lusca';
var config = require('./db');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var mongoStore = connectMongo(session);

module.exports = function(app) {
 // app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(methodOverride());
}
```

User index where i will handle all crud operation for user

app > api > user > index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./user.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.post('/',controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Probably you should be specifying `/api/users`, not `api/users`.

Comment: Try to do not ask duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644624

Answer (score 0):

**1st:**

To handle all request

*Bind application-level middleware to an instance of the **app object** by using the **app.use()** and app.METHOD() functions, where METHOD is the HTTP method of the request that the middleware function handles **(such as GET, PUT, or POST)** in lowercase*.

This example shows a middleware function with no mount path. The function is executed every time the ***app receives a request***.

```
app.use(function(req,res)
   {

        res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html');
       console.log("Not found....I will handle *unhandle* rout here for you");
})
```

// `app.get('*', function(req, res)` use the above function instead of this

But this function at the end so it will only excute when no route path found to the app object.
[Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

**2nd:**

To handle createuser

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./user.controller');

var router = express.Router();
// you must define route which you want to handle in user file
router.get('/api/user', controller.index);

router.post('/',controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

**Update working example with some explanation**

Your app.js file

```
var express=require('express')
var app=express()
app.use('api/user',require('./user'))
app.use('/',require('./user'))
app.use(function(req,res)
       {
    res.sendfile('stack10.html')
    console.log("Not found....I will handle *unhandle* rout here for you");
})
app.listen(8080,function()

          {
    console.log("server listening on port 8080")
})
```

**user.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var app=express()
router.get('/api/user', function(req, res) {
  res.send('respond for ..../api/user')
});
router.get('/',function (req,res) {
   res.send('respose for ..../')
})
module.exports = router;
```

> Your app.use will be `app.use(api/user)` while in user will be `router.get(/api/user)` so when u try http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user
>   your response will be `respond for ..../api/user`

Comment: I could not understand what you have implemented in answer it is confusing me because you mentioned file names different.

Comment: second one is just for your understanding copy that paste it and run in your environment for more understanding

Comment: so you are saying first one is the answer according to my code ?

Comment: And you can try it yourself according to your code.

Comment: yeah if you still confuse post your project tag me on GitHub or post the link here i will make changes in your project if you still stuck from two days

Comment: @Adiii can not change folder structure as per requirement i have to follow as i mentioned in question, can you provide me example the way i have implemented the code.I think express.js need to be fixed according to my implementation.

Comment: @hussain dear that i run local work properly if need more help i am here adilm717@gmail.com email me will help you out ..i cant say thing here.and i think you dont have background knowledge of node.js thats way you looking confuse

Comment: I understand i can make it work with your approach , but i am asking the way i have file structure i want to make it work my code.

Comment: then just past the app.use in your api file